# Esper - detect event after absence

Tags: esper

I found out that it is possible to detect the absence of an event using for example: 
select * from pattern [every EventX -> (timer:interval(10 sec) and not EventX)], but is it also possible to detect the presence of an event after it was absent? Using prior perhaps? And is it possible to use one statement for detecting both absence and presence?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its sounds like you are looking for this

```
every EventX -> (timer:interval(10 sec) and not EventX) -> Event X
```

...adding some time interval withing which the event should arrive...

```
every EventX -> (timer:interval(10 sec) and not EventX) -> Event X where timer:within(10)
```

Try an outer join to detect with multiple patterns:

```
select * from pattern[...].win:length_batch(1) as pattern1 full outer join pattern[...].win:length_batch(1) as pattern2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will try this out. The idea is that a sensor is sending an event every 10 seconds and I want to fire a notification saying the sensor is offline when no event is detected from this sensor after 10 seconds. But when the sensor starts sending events again on the regular interval I want to send an "online" notification.

Comment: It does seem to work but in the 10 sec. example if it takes longer than 20 seconds for the events to arrive again (after the absence) it stops working. I somehow need to detect when the sensor is back online after a longer (unknown) period of time. Is that possible?

Comment: I would try inserting into a named window when an absence is detected. When an event comes in and has a row in the named window select and delete the row and that is the "online" indicator.