# Esper output clause with named windows

Tags: esper

I have a question about using the output clause in combination with a named window, patterns and the insert into statement.
My goal is to detect the absence of an event, store it in a named window and when the events start coming again select and delete the row and use that as an "online" indicator (see [Esper - detect event after absence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426151/esper-detect-event-after-absence))
I somehow want to be able limit the rate of events when there are multiple offline - online events in a short period of time (disable false positives). I thought the output clause could help here but when I use that on the insert into statement no events are stored in the named window. Is this the right approach or is there an other way to limit the events in this scenario?

This is my code in Esper EPL online:

```
create schema MonitorStats(id string, time string, host string, alert string);

create window MonitorWindow.win:keepall() as select id, alert, time, host from MonitorStats;

insert into MonitorWindow select a.id as id, 'offline' as alert, a.time as time, a.host as host from pattern 
 [every a=MonitorStats(id='1234') -> (timer:interval(25 sec) and not MonitorStats(id=a.id))];

on pattern[every b=MonitorStats(id='1234') -> (timer:interval(25 sec) and MonitorStats(id=b.id))]
select and delete b.id as id, 'online' as alert, b.time as time, b.host as host from MonitorWindow as win
where win.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may insert output events into another stream and use "output first every".

```
insert into DetectedStream select ....;
select * from DetectedStream output first every 10 seconds;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added my EPL online statements. With your example I still receive multiple "online" outputs. Is there a way to simplify the above statements and use the output first clause for both "offline" and "online" events?

Comment: on pattern[...] insert into DetectedStream select and delete ....; select * from DetectedStream output first every 10 seconds; (listen to the last statement)

Comment: Thanks, but with this approach I get the first "offline" event from the DetectedStream but not the first "offline" - "online" pair of events right? How would I achieve that?